# What's the name of that tv sci-fi horror series with a truck driver who can't escape a town? he won't get a cup of coffee

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

Young trucker is rocking out to hard rock/metal music and asks an old man for directions as he keeps looping through the town. He tells him if you slow down, enjoy the scenery and stop (at a Diner in the town) for a nice cup of coffee, he'll get out and find the highway. In the end, he goes into the diner where he's confronted by everyone and the old man forcing the pot of coffee towards him and he asks, "what do you people want from me?" After drinking the coffee, he becomes the town's newest resident and the sign changes the population count.

This was one episode in a 1980's or 1990's horror or science fiction TV show, which aired in colour, in English, in the USA. It's kinda Twilight Zone, Tales from the Darkside-ish.

Looked in synopsis of Monsters, Tales from the crypt, Ray Bradbury, Twilight Zone 80's & Forest Whitaker's, The Outer Limits, Amazing Stories, The Hitchhiker, Tales from the Darkside, but nothing describes such.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: E.G. was this one episode in the series, or was all of the series about this trucker.

Comment: This was one episode in the series

Comment: was the episode in black and white, color, what kind of rock music was playing? 60's, 70's, 80's etc...? English language, aired in the USA? etc...

Comment: Hard rock/metal. Definitely color. Just updated.

Comment: Aired in USA and English.

Comment: It could possibly be the early 2000's, but I seriously doubt it. The music playing the driver was listening to was 80's type hair metal, so I'm defiantly thinking early 1990's or late 1980's.

Answer (score 10):

"Escapes"(1986 TV movie)?

This was an anthology movie that was hosted by Vincent Price. It included 5 stories and the one you describe sounds like the 3rd story in this, called "Coffee Break". I remembered renting this one when I was in my late teens and I remembered the population sign changing at the end. I think it was a straight to video movie, even though IMDb calls it a TV movie, and it was shot on videotape. Below is the IMDb page:

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091016/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2

Aaaah! Just found that episode on YouTube. Here it is.

It ends with the protagonist shouting (in slo-mo)

> "***What do you people want from me!!***"

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU. I saw this around age 10 and that last scene with menacing with the coffee pot was so hilarious.